# Can I use a charger to power a motor?

Tags: dc, battery-charging, dc-motor, charger

I working on a home pet project for which I bought a rather powerful moter. It is a 24V 90W motor, which says the "Load current" is 5.7A.

I now want to power it with my wall power, so I thought of buying a car battery charger to make the motor run. Something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/12V-24V-10A-Universal-Car-Battery-Charger-Motorcycle-Battery-Charger-Lead-Acid-Battery-Charger-Free-Shipping/32546270215.html) for example:

[image]

In the description it says it has the following properties:

```
Rated Power: 50-60Hz
Power: 140W
Actual Output Current: 12V-10A   24V-7.5A
```

As far as I understand it simply gives 7.5A at 24V, so that should do it. But since I'm an enormous beginner I don't actually know if this would work at all.

Does anybody know if I can buy this to power my motor? All tips are welcome!

Comment: The initial surge while starting the motor is going to be much larger than the continuous current. To what extent, and how that may effect your charger, I cannot say.

Comment: One problem with those specs is that its power rating is 140W, but it outputs 120W at 12V and 180W at 24V. Which tells you one thing : you can't trust anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any DC motor that does not have an electronic speed controller (ESC) will draw much more that rated current for a fraction of a second or so when it is first switched on. Any type of electronic power supply needs to be able to supply that current for a brief time. Look for the "stall" or "locked rotor" current of the motor.

If you don't need speed control, the best alternative is probably to buy a 150 VA transformer and a rectifier. The motor will probably operate ok with full-wave rectified, un-filtered DC power from a 24 VAC source.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I learned a lot from it. So I just emailed the seller of the motor what the stall current is. Let's say the stall current is 8A, can I in that case buy a 220VAC to 24VDC transformer with a max of 10A (for example this one: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/220VAC-to-24VDC-Power-Supply-250W-10A-Constant-Voltage-Switch-Mode-Driver-Transformer-Fanless-Indoor-Aluminum/32786160809.html). Would that work, or do I need a higher maximum Ampere?

Comment: Ok, I got an answer from the supplier. They say the stall current is "About 20A". So I looked around and I guess something like this would be more suitable (500W): https://www.aliexpress.com/item/SE-600-24-110VAC-220VAC-to-24vDC-Power-transformer-24V-dc-switching-power-supply-600w/32283122192.html Do you think that would work?

Comment: That would probably work.

Comment: Alright, I ordered that one. Thanks for the joy of knowledge which you've given me :)

Answer (score 2):

These battery chargers need some voltage to enable the charging circuit.

You can only use this charger to drive the motor if the voltage detection circuit is bypassed.